# Compare the 2nd strings characters with the 1st string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to figure out a challenge in Free Code Camp which states the following:

> Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.

I understand how to do this if the 2nd string has a single character or if the 1st string has the 2nd string contained in the exact same sequence (e.g. "hello", "hel" and not "hello", "olleh"). But I can't figure out yet the correct approach to tackle this challenge.

Here is my code...

```
function mutation(arr) {

 var myArray = arr.splice(1).toString().toLowerCase();
 var splicedArray = arr.toString().toLowerCase();

  if (splicedArray.search(myArray) != -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Any combination which has a different sequence of the characters evaluates to false.

```
 // e.g this is false
 mutation(['Alien', 'line'])
```

What is the right way to complete this task?

Comment: [`charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

Comment: You want to use `.indexOf` instead of `search`

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I think so. I'm coming up with something like this using the for loop..... string1.indexOf(string2.charAt( [ i ] )). What do you think?

Comment: @RolandJegorov: Sounds good! (though `string2.charAt(i)`, no array literal)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I'll try it and get back. In the end, someone of the participants should get the accepted answer points. :)

Comment: @RolandJegorov I've really got enough points :-) If you've figured it out, you can [answer the question yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Bergi Hey, this is what I got, which, alas, returns true if the first char is equal. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXdWQo. Oh boy, I feel bad having a hard time to comprehend this even if have little experience with JS :(

Comment: If the first character was found, you don't want to `return true` immediately. You want to continue searching for all the characters, and only after the loop, when you have found *all* of them, return `true`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, haha. I got it. Much obliged to you. Yay. So excited now. :D Here is it  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXdWQo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bergi I figured out the answer. Also he was so kind to allow me to post the answer myself. Here it is...

```
function mutation(arr) {

   var string2 = arr.splice(1).toString().toLowerCase();
   var string1 = arr.toString().toLowerCase();
  for(var i = 0; i < string2.length; i++) {
    if (string1.indexOf(string2.charAt(i)) == -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If someone like me (JS beginner) encounters this task and finds this solution, here are some notable resources to read through if you do not know the methods used here..

- [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Difference between .slice() and .splice() methods](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2014/02/javascript-array-slice-vs-splice.html)

Comment: @Bergi Did you remove **.toString()** on purpose? If so then Dev Tools returns this as false. The arguments passed in the function are array elements so they can't be compared for every character. Maybe I was unclear with the task? If so then my bad --> `mutation(['hello', 'hel']);`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
/**
 * Match function that operates on a data array with two elements, where the 
 * first element is the query and the second element is the searchable data.
 *
 * Returns true if the query string contains all of the letters of the searchable
 * data string.
 * 
 * @param  {Array} data - contains query and searchable string data
 * 
 * @return {Boolean} if a match occured
 */
var match = function (data) {
    // Convert strings to arrays.
    var query = Array.prototype.slice.call(data[0]);
    var searchableData = Array.prototype.slice.call(data[1]);

    // Every query string character should occur in the searchable data.
    return query.every(function (search) {

        // Only some of the searchable data characters should occur in the query data.
        return searchableData.some(function (target) {
            return search === target;
        });
    });
};

match([ 'abc', 'xyzadefbhijc' ]); // returns true
match([ 'abq', 'xyzadefbhijc' ]); // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

My mutation

```
function mutation(arr) {

  var string2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var string1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();

  for(var i = 0; i < string2.length; i++) {
    if (string1.indexOf(string2.charAt(i)) == -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same can be done using map:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var one = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var two = arr[1].toLowerCase().split('');
  var match = true;
  two.map(function(val){
    if(one.indexOf(val) === -1){
      match = false;
    }
  });
  return match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var src=arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var dist=arr[1].toLowerCase();
  for(var i=0;i<dist.length;i++){
    if(src.indexOf(dist[i])<0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(mutation(["voonoo", "no"]))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.